# What are some comparative studies on program termination verification tools?

Tags: software-verification

Comparative studies of tools like AProver, 2LS

Comment: Did you mean [AProVE](http://aprove.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/)?

Comment: The body of your question should be complete unto itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by nekketsuuu, SV-COMP has a termination category, and the [Termination Competition](http://termination-portal.org/wiki/Termination_Competition) has been going on for quite some time (there is some overlap).

It depends on what kind of termination you are interested in. [This paper](http://verify.rwth-aachen.de/giesl/papers/JAR-AProVE.pdf) on AProVE gives an overview of that tool, which covers many of the techniques involved in general program termination analysis and types of programs that can be handled, though it does not really analyze the comparative strengths of different tools.

Sadly, I'm not aware of any modern overview paper that does this, which is unfortunate. The tool description papers of the competition participants for your category of choice would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

How about looking at Competition on Software Verification (SV-COMP) held at TACAS? There is a category of termination. For example, [here](https://sv-comp.sosy-lab.org/2017/) is a link to SV-COMP 2017.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answerers I'm not aware of such a study although it would be nice to have some. Instead, I would point to several benchmarks that the authors of these tools produce. A comparative study should benefit from it. I will set this as a community wiki so that other people can add references to other benchmarks/studies:

**Benchmarks**

[Stainless verification framework](https://github.com/epfl-lara/stainless/tree/master/frontends/benchmarks/termination)

[Termination Problems Data Base](http://cl2-informatik.uibk.ac.at/mercurial.cgi/TPDB)

**Comparative studies**